# vuetify icon doesn't show properly

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I created a selection field based on the [example from vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#slots) in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/veevalidate-components-vuetify-forked-xdph35?file=/src/components/SelectAll.vue).

But somehow the top "Select All" section didn't display properly.
[image]

It should looks like this:
[image]

Any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computed properties need to be declared as class property getter / setter.

Ref: https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/class-component.html#computed-properties

```js
/*...*/
  get likesAllFruit() {
    return this.selectedFruits.length === this.fruits.length;
  }

  get likesSomeFruit() {
    return this.selectedFruits.length > 0 && !this.likesAllFruit;
  }

  get icon() {
    if (this.likesAllFruit) return "mdi-checkbox-marked";
    if (this.likesSomeFruit) return "mdi-checkbox-blank-outline";
    return "mdi-checkbox-blank-outline";
  }
/*...*/
```